# Cart summary_count not updated when "add to cart" is pressed

Tags: magento2, cart, knockoutjs, magento2.4

I'm using the following code to show the total number of items in a users cart:

`<span data-bind="text: JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('mage-cache-storage')).cart.summary_count"></span>`

It works and shows the correct number of items, but when "add to cart" is pressed and the item is added the value isn't update unless the page is refreshed.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the dom is loaded your data-bindings will run. Your code will take the cart.summary_count from local storage and update it correctly.

However, the add to cart action is executed using ajax so there will be no page load, so your code will not run again, thus you will not get the new value from local storage.
The add to cart action will update the value in local storage. However, your value will not be updated.

Normally one would not read directly from localstorage as you are doing in your code. I would implement it like this and uses the built in functionality in the minicart:

```
<div data-bind="scope: 'minicart_counter'">
    <?=__('Items in cart:')?>
    <span data-bind="html: getCartParamUnsanitizedHtml('summary_count')"></span>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "minicart_counter": {
                        "component": "Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Kristoffer. I'm still getting my head around using JS on the frontend. If you don't mind me asking, where did you obtain `getCartParamUnsanitizedHtml` as I'm not finding any of this in the documentation?

Comment: Also, I'm getting an error in the console: `[ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart" component.`

Comment: hmm, that is strange because I actually tested this code locally and it worked. The Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart is trying to load this file: vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js. I can not see any reason why you should not have it. Could be an issue with static content maybe, not sure. The function getCartParamUnsanitizedHtml is inside the minicart.js javascript module. Feel free to ask if you have any questions, no problems.

Comment: I have created a custom header which doesn't use Magento's features such as the cart. I've implemented my own which works great apart from this issue. Maybe it's just a case of including the components. Would I do this in my themes root's `requirejs-config.js`?

Comment: The code should work like this, there is no need to modify requirejs-config.js. If you check your local magento do you have the file? vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js. I could paste all my code I used to test maybe and you can try it on your installation.

Comment: It has something to do with me removing the header.in `default.xml`. I have made a separate question on it: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/326257/referenceblock-name-header-container-remove-true-removes-minicart-functi